# Chrome plugin - Permission chrome-devtools://*/* is unknown or URL pattern is malformed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am maintaining one extension for google chrome and I'm receiving complaints from random users saying that it just stopped working.

The error message in "extensions" section is this:

```
Chrome plugin - Permission chrome-devtools://*/* is unknown or URL pattern is malformed
```

It seems it's not a very popular issue - I wasn't able to find any trace of that. My permissions section of the manifest file looks like this:

```
    "permissions": [
       "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "chrome-devtools://*/*"
    ]
```

And it works just fine for most people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) you will find that only valid schemes are: `'*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp' | 'chrome-extension'`. I'm guessing that your recent problems are due to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87815) being fixed.

Comment: That issue is not relevant (closed over four months ago).

Comment: This issue is about access to `chrome-devtools://` scheme that was available till Apr 18, 2012. OP never mentioned when complains started.

Comment: Ok, but how can you change or hook the chrome-devtools window and its functions if you can't enable access to chrome-devtools?

Comment: @NoBugs: There are [**`devtools API`**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html) for manipulation and access, what is that you are looking at ??

Comment: That works, but trying to modify the other panels doesn't work. For example: `window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 window.setTimeout(function() {
 window.parent.WebInspector.NetworkLogView.addEventListener("RequestSelected",function(e) {
  console.log('request');console.log(e);
 })
 },10000);
}, false); ` doesn't work, yet in the same place `chrome.devtools.panels.create(...` does work.

Comment: I hoped the answer was not that there is no solution, but that appears to be the case.