# Can't register style to dev-tools

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I created a test extension, to change a few things and maybe add some features to Firefox built-in devtools.

I set up a basic extension, with content css and the usual files, and chrome.manifest:

```
content devtooltweaks   content/
style chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul chrome://devtooltweaks/content/devToolStyle.css
```

Although I can go to "chrome://devtooltweaks/content/devToolStyle.css" and see that file exists in the browser, DOM inspector doesn't show the style applying, I can't see the stylesheet listed either. It's been a long time since I did extension development, is there a step I'm missing here? Or is it not permitted to change the built in dev tools, similar to how it's [not permitted in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574305/chrome-plugin-permission-chrome-devtools-is-unknown-or-url-pattern-is-ma)?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you open them in a separate window?

Comment: Nope, figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the style is imported, but not shown as a stylesheet in the DOM Inspector, I also may not have been using `firefox -purgecaches`. It's working now.